# How to round/remove trailing ".0" zeros in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to see if I can remove the trailing zeros from this phone number column.

Example:

```
0
1      8.00735e+09
2      4.35789e+09
3      6.10644e+09
```

The type in this column is an object, and I tried to round it but I am getting an error.  I checked a couple of them I know they are in this format "8007354384.0", and want to get rid of the trailing zeros with the decimal point.

Sometimes I received in this format and sometimes I don't, they will be integer numbers.  I would like to check if the phone column has a trailing zero, then remove it.

I have this code but I'm stuck on how to check for trailing zeros for each row.

```
data.ix[data.phone.str.contains('.0'), 'phone']
```

I get an error => `*** ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`.  I believe the issue is because some rows have empty data, which sometime I do receive.  The code above should be able to skip an empty row.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I'm new to pandas but so far it's an useful library.  Your help will be appreciated.

**Note**
The provided example above, the first row has an empty data, which I do sometimes I get.  Just to make sure this is not represented as 0 for phone number.

Also empty data is considered a string, so it's a mix of floats and string, if rows are empty.

Answer (score 17):

use `astype(np.int64)`

```
s = pd.Series(['', 8.00735e+09, 4.35789e+09, 6.10644e+09])
mask = pd.to_numeric(s).notnull()
s.loc[mask] = s.loc[mask].astype(np.int64)
s

0              
1    8007350000
2    4357890000
3    6106440000
dtype: object
```

Comment: this is not working because of that empty data in the first row, `*** ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: ''`.  I am not familiar with dtype object, but it looks this is being a treated as string.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I noticed, since the first row is an empty data, it's considered as a string, which throws that error.  Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: What do you want the result to be for that row.

Comment: for that row it should be empty, so I'm ok with the empty string ( '' ), the rest I want the trailing zeroes removed.

Comment: it seems the wright way...but still, I have no idea why this is not working in my case :( -- I have
`df.loc[df.my_var.notnull(),'my_var'].astype(np.int64)`

Comment: Was there any definitive answer for this? I have the same kind of question, cant get it to work. i've tried this approach and the below.

Comment: There are many nuances specific to the context of the actual problem.  OP never got back with answers that would have clarified the context.  Feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 15):

In Pandas/NumPy, integers are not allowed to take NaN values, and arrays/series (including dataframe columns) are homogeneous in their datatype --- so having a column of integers where some entries are `None`/`np.nan` is downright [impossible](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na).

EDIT:`data.phone.astype('object')`
should do the trick; in this case, Pandas treats your column as a series of generic Python objects, rather than a specific datatype (e.g. `str`/`float`/`int`), at the cost of performance if you intend to run any heavy computations with this data (probably not in your case).

Assuming you want to keep those NaN entries, your approach of converting to strings is a valid possibility:

`data.phone.astype(str).str.split('.', expand = True)[0]`

should give you what you're looking for (there are alternative string methods you can use, such as `.replace` or `.extract`, but `.split` seems the most straightforward in this case).

Alternatively, if you are only interested in the display of floats (unlikely I'd suppose), you can do `pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.0f}'.format)`, which doesn't actually affect your data.

Answer (score 11):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542713/10750106) by cs95 removes trailing “.0” in one row.

```
df = df.round(decimals=0).astype(object)
```

Comment: Pretty sure [I offered OP this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542657/round-pandas-column-with-precision-but-no-trailing-0/47542713?noredirect=1#comment104856358_47542713) (happened under the answer you linked, too), apparently no bueno. No idea what OP wants ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Just do

```
data['phone'] = data['phone'].astype(str)          
data['phone'] = data['phone'].str.replace('.0', ' ')
```

which uses a [regex style lookup](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) on all entries in the column and replaces any '.0' matches with blank space. For example

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [['bob','39384954.0'],['Lina','23827484.0']], 
    columns = ['user','phone'], index = [1,2]
)

data['phone'] = data['phone'].astype(str)
data['phone'] = data['phone'].str.replace('.0', ' ')
print data

   user     phone
1   bob  39384954
2  Lina  23827484
```

Comment: I tried to do that but I get an error => `*** TypeError: to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'downcast'`.  Here is my code `pd.to_numeric(data.phone, errors='ignore', downcast='integer')`

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?

Comment: pandas version is "0.18.1"

Comment: What if I have several columns, how do I do that in one command?

Besides the fact that it did not work. (Don't know why)

Comment: I had to specify the optional parameter regex=False in the str.replace function.  the default true value was replacing all 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 9):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([ None, np.nan, '',8.00735e+09,  4.35789e+09, 6.10644e+09])

s_new = s.fillna('').astype(str).str.replace(".0","",regex=False)
s_new
```

Here I filled null values with empty string, converted series to string type, replaced `.0` with empty string.
This outputs:

```
0              
1              
2              
3    8007350000
4    4357890000
5    6106440000
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

So Pandas automatically assign data type by looking at type of data in the event when you have mix type of data like some rows are NaN and some has int value there is huge possibilities it would assign `dtype: object` or `float64`

**EX 1:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10934000000], ['nick', 1534000000], ['juli', 1412000000]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Phone'])

>>> df
   Name        Phone
0   tom  10934000000
1  nick   1534000000
2  juli   1412000000

>>> df.dtypes
Name     object
Phone     int64
dtype: object
```

In above example pandas assume data type int64 reason being neither of row has NaN and all the rows in Phone column has integer value.

**EX 2:**

```
 >>> data = [['tom'], ['nick', 1534000000], ['juli', 1412000000]]
 >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Phone'])
 >>> df

 Name         Phone
0   tom           NaN
1  nick  1.534000e+09
2  juli  1.412000e+09

>>> df.dtypes
Name      object
Phone    float64
dtype: object
```

To answer to your actual question, to get rid of .0 at the end you can do something like this

**Solution 1:**

```
>>> data = [['tom', 9785000000.0], ['nick', 1534000000.0], ['juli', 1412000000]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Phone'])
>>> df
   Name         Phone
0   tom  9.785000e+09
1  nick  1.534000e+09
2  juli  1.412000e+09

>>> df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].astype(int).astype(str)
>>> df
   Name       Phone
0   tom  9785000000
1  nick  1534000000
2  juli  1412000000
```

**Solution 2:**

```
>>> df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].astype(str).str.replace('.0', '', regex=False)
>>> df
   Name       Phone
0   tom  9785000000
1  nick  1534000000
2  juli  1412000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `str.isnumeric` with `astype` and `loc`:

```
s = pd.Series(['', 8.00735e+09, 4.35789e+09, 6.10644e+09])
c = s.str.isnumeric().astype(bool)
s.loc[c] = s.loc[c].astype(np.int64)
print(s)
```

And now:

```
print(s)
```

Outputs:

```
0              
1    8007350000
2    4357890000
3    6106440000
dtype: object
```

Comment: Seems like I cannot get it to work. I am making c my dataframe column like so , `c=df['id'].str.isnumeric().astype(bool)`  . then doing `df['id'].loc[c] =  df['id'].loc(c).astype(np.int64)`  . Any ideas on this?

Comment: any ideas Monica?

Comment: @excelguy Change: `df['id'].loc[c] = df['id'].loc(c).astype(np.int64)` to `df['id'].loc[c] = df['id'].loc[c].astype(np.int64)`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [pandas nullable integers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) (the solution assumes that input Series values are either empty strings or floating point numbers):

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
s = pd.Series(['', 8.00735e+09, 4.35789e+09, 6.10644e+09])
s.replace('', np.nan).astype('Int64')
```

Output (pandas-0.25.1):

```
0           NaN
1    8007350000
2    4357890000
3    6106440000
dtype: Int64
```

Advantages of the solution:

- The output values are either integers or missing values (not 'object' data type)
- Efficient

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the data format the telephone number is stored.

If it is in an numeric format changing to an integer might solve the problem

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TelephoneNumber': [123.0, 234]})
df['TelephoneNumber'] =  df['TelephoneNumber'].astype('int32')
```

If it is really a string you can replace and re-assign the column.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TelephoneNumber': ['123.0', '234']})
df2['TelephoneNumber'] = df2['TelephoneNumber'].str.replace('.0', '')
```

Comment: and also need to add regex=False as df2['TelephoneNumber'].str.replace('.0', '',regex=False) as in Shyam Bhimani's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
tt = 8.00735e+09
time = int(np.format_float_positional(tt)[:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is still interesting:
I had the problem that I round the df and get the trailing zeros.
Here is what I did.

```
new_df = np.round(old_df,3).astype(str)
```

Then all trailing zeros were gone in the new_df.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem with empty rings in some rows.

The most helpful answer on this [Python - Remove decimal and zero from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774069/python-remove-decimal-and-zero-from-string) link helped me.

Comment: This should be a comment, no need to add it as separate answer. you will be able to add comments after gaining some reputations on platform.