# Python - Remove decimal and zero from string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading several spreadsheets into a data frame and there is an ID field that is a string in some spreadsheets and a number in others. I've converted it into a string, which is the data type I need, but I'm ending up with some IDs that have a ".0" at the end. How do I remove the decimal and zero?

Example: ID number 805096730.0 should be 805096730

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[805096730.0,805096730.0]})

df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
print (df)
          ID
0  805096730
1  805096730
```

Or add parameter `dtype`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, dtype={'ID':str})
```

Answer (score 2):

Check type of your numbers before converting them to strings. It seems that they are floats, rather than integers. If this is the case, convert your numbers to integers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([123.0, 456.0])
df = df.apply(int, axis=1)

0    123
1    456
```

Then, convert it into strings:

```
df = df.apply(str)
print(df.iloc[1])

'456'
```