# round pandas column with precision but no trailing 0

Tags: python, pandas, csv, rounding

Not duplicate because I'm asking about pandas `round()`.

I have a `dataframe` with some columns with numbers. I run

```
df = df.round(decimals=6)
```

That successfully truncated the long decimals instead of `15.36785699998` correctly writing: `15.367857`, but I still get `1.0`  or `16754.0` with a trailing zero.

How do I get rid of the trailing zeros in all the columns, once I ran pandas `df.round()`  ?

I want to save the dataframe as a csv, and need the data to show the way I wish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df = df.round(decimals=6).astype(object)
```

Converting to `object` will allow mixed representations. But, keep in mind that this is not very useful from a performance standpoint.

---

```
df

           A          B
0   0.149724  -0.770352
1   0.606370  -1.194557
2  10.000000  10.000000
3  10.000000  10.000000
4   0.843729  -1.571638
5  -0.427478  -2.028506
6  -0.583209   1.114279
7  -0.437896   0.929367
8  -1.025460   1.156107
9   0.535074   1.085753

df.round(6).astype(object)

          A         B
0  0.149724 -0.770352
1   0.60637  -1.19456
2        10        10
3        10        10
4  0.843729  -1.57164
5 -0.427478  -2.02851
6 -0.583209   1.11428
7 -0.437896  0.929367
8  -1.02546   1.15611
9  0.535074   1.08575
```

Comment: Wow!!  So much talk about `fs['mycol'].as_type(str).str.replace('.0,',',')` and I even went so far as to texfile.readlines with that replace...  after all else was done. This is great!!

Comment: Can you provide any explanation about _why_ Pandas renders integral floats in a dtype object series this way? Is this behaviour documented? It seems like a dangerous thing to rely on if not (and converting to `object` purely to solve a representational issue seems inadvisable).

Comment: @MarkDickinson Not very knowledgable on the "why" bit. And yes, I usually add the obligatory disclaimer about performance, but for this question it was alright because `I want to save the dataframe as a csv, and need the data to show the way I wish.`, so it seems it was _only_ to solve a representational issue and nothing more.

Comment: why choose 6 here? what if you just want to remove trailing .0s?

Comment: @excelguy I chose 6 because the OP chose 6 (check the question)

Comment: thanks, what if you dont want to display decimals and not round these? can this be done? my numbers will just have a `.0` appended.

Comment: @excelguy Did you just want a flooring operation `df['col'] = np.floor(df['col'])`?

Comment: no sorry, i dont want to round, i simply want to remove `.0` from end of each string.

Comment: @excelguy ohhh, just do `df.astype(object)` it will not display the decimal point when printing. Otherwise, you can convert it to string and then strip trailing zeros via string operation. Up to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204225/discussion-between-excelguy-and-cs95).

Comment: Hey would you mind replying here please, I'm at work and don't want to open a chatroom. @excelguy

Comment: sure, maybe look at my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326277/pandas-trailing-0s-on-object-column . Cant seem to get it with object or string and removal.