# Prevent trailing zero with pandas "to_csv"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, d3.js, casting

I'm trying to export a CSV string to a D3 web application, but the command `to_csv` insists on adding a trailing 0 to the data, which prevents a proper use by D3.

Here's a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

My (simplified) dataframe is:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Alex',20.0000, 50.650]],columns=['Name','Age', 'Weight'])
   Name   Age  Weight
0  Alex  20.0   50.65
```

`df['Age']` contains a `float`, as indicated by:

```
>>> df['Age']
0    20.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Then based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542713/3976696) I run `.astype(object)` to get the format I would like:

```
>>> df=df.astype(object)
   Name Age Weight
0  Alex  20  50.65
```

Now, `df['Age']` contains an `object`, with no trailing zero:

```
>>> df['Age']
0    20
Name: Age, dtype: object
```

That's what I would like to export with `to_csv`, but this command reappends a trailing 0 to the number, which I want to avoid:

```
>>> df_csv = df.to_csv(sep=',', index = False)
>>> df_csv
'Name,Age,Weight\nAlex,20.0,50.65\n'
```

I tried using `df_csv = df.to_csv(sep=',', index = False, float_format='%.0f')` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882439/3976696), but that doesn't work because there are other floats in my dataframe for which I wish to keep non-zero decimals.

How could I prevent this trailing 0 to appear for numbers with no decimals?

Comment: I should point out that the answers seem to be misformatted, maybe because `d3.js` is one of the tags. I went ahead and fixed everyone's formatting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another way using Pandas replace :

```py
df = df.astype(str)
df = df.replace(to_replace = "\.0+$",value = "", regex = True)
```

This way you don't need to import any extra module.

Comment: Works on strings with spaces as well.

Comment: Actually, the string to be replaced should be `"\.0+$"`, to avoid also modifying numbers such as `0.0286`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(int)`

this gets me

```py
    Name    Age     Weight
0   Alex    20  50.65
```

converting a column to type `object` essentially allows the column to hold floats, ints, strings etc. vs a typed column which will only hold that type.

And converting it to a csv:

```py
df_csv = df.to_csv(sep=',', index = False)
    
'Name,Age,Weight\r\nAlex,20,50.65\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I tried that, but I would need a "batch" approach, because there are hundreds of columns (some which may be added by a third party in the future). Therefore I would prefer to avoid hardcoding individual column names, which was the advantage of `.astype(obj)`. Do you know why the `object` type effectively removes the trailing 0 in the df, but not in the resulting csv?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that will work as long as you don't have spaces within your string columns.

Use `to_string()` after `astype(object)` instead of `to_csv()`. This will preserve the numeric formats, but it will use spaces as the separator. As long as you don't have spaces in any of your other fields, you can use regular expressions to convert the spaces to commas.

```py
import re
df = df.astype(object)
df_string = re.sub(" +", ",", df.to_string(index=False))
print(df_string)
#Name,Age,Weight
#Alex,20,50.65
```

Now write `df_string` to your file:

```py
with open('path/to/some/file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really hate this disprecancy between `pandas.DataFrame.to_string` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`. However I salvaged the data by copying it into a new DataFrame using `applymap`:

```py
df_fixed = df.applymap(lambda cell: int(cell) if str(cell).endswith('.0') else cell)
```

```
>>> df.to_csv()
',Name,Age,Weight\n0,Alex,20.0,50.65\n'

>>> df_fixed.to_csv()
',Name,Age,Weight\n0,Alex,20,50.65\n'
```

Note this doesn't work with large numbers (e.g. 10**7) because it'll start using e notation (1e7)