# Pandas, trailing .0's on object column

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to eliminate my ".0" on a specified column. The dtype for the column is an object. I export my dataframe as a .txt file and it keeps showing with decimals. I do not want to round.

I've tried several methods,

`df['foDealId'] = df['foDealId'].astype(str).replace('\.0','',regex=True)` . I get no change in my data.

and

`df['foDealId'] = df['foDealId'].str.replace('.0','')` . I get my number truncated in the middle of it where there was a 0. ie 2451669285571 14

and

```
df['foDealId'].loc[mask] = df['foDealId'].loc[mask].astype(np.int64)
df['foDealId'] = pd.to_numeric(df.foDealId, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
```

any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round pandas column with precision but no trailing 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542657/round-pandas-column-with-precision-but-no-trailing-0)

Comment: Hello, like it's duplicated (ps it's not me the -1 :D)
look this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403907/how-to-round-remove-traling-0-zeros-in-pandas-column#42403995)

Comment: I've tried that post as well.  Also i dont want to round. Let me update with that try.

Comment: Add an r before ur regex  `replace(r'\.0',`.. Should do the trick

Comment: If the column is an integer column, (numbers where you don't care about leading 0s) then you may want to consider using `.astype('Int64')` (note the capital I). Normal `int` dtypes cannot hold NaN, but `Int64` can. If those are ID numbers where there can be leading 0s, you should probably specify `dtype={'foDealId': 'str'}` for the column when you import the data, and likely you wont have any upcasting to float which leads to this problem.

Comment: @Datanovice , tried that, still not working. sigh.

Comment: @ALollz , tried your first suggestion, getting `TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype` ,  How do i specify dtype? Im not reading csv for my data.

Comment: Can you add 2-3 rows of sample data along with your expected output please.