# Removing .0 from pandas dataframe without converting it to string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If we need to convert 104.0 to only 104, without using %g that converts it into string. Is there any method in python - pandas by which we can check if a column is float and I do not want to convert it to string or cast to integer, yet make only 140.0 to 140 and have 139.58 to 139.58. Please help?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542713/4909087),  you can skip the call to `round()`.

Comment: Predominantly I am writing a data frame into a .csv and reading again from that csv and writing into a remote filer location. So I want the float data values not to have .0 at the end. I dont want to convert the floats into string.

Comment: `.astype(object)` doesn't convert the column to a string.

Comment: I do not want to convert it to object datatype, but I want to have it in same float format

Comment: That is not possible. You can't have the cake and eat it too. Either you remain satisfied with the current representation or you convert the dtype to object (NOTE THAT THEY ARE STILL NUMBERS, but the operations are no longer vectorizable).

Comment: Well my scenario is that I want it removed while converting it to csv. That is the format required as per business logic. I cant change them. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in (at least) two ways.

Let's say we have a Series that looks like this:

```
x = pd.Series([140.0, 120.0, 100.0])
x

0    140.0
1    120.0
2    100.0
dtype: float64
```

You can then use the *astype()* method:

```
x = x.astype(int)
x

0    140
1    120
2    100
dtype: int64
```

As for Python, remember you have the *int()* function.

```
x = int(140.0)
x
140
```

Comment: no, but when I use int(143.89) the nit converts it into 144. But I want float to remain as float, but just want to remove .0 from other float numbers