# Python number format

Tags: python-3.x, format

I am very new to Python. I have DataFrame with column called quantity. I am able to read value using `df['QTY']`.

I need for format value like below

```
0.00 -> 0

12.0 -> 12

100.00 -> 100

12.00 -> 12

12 -> 12

123.34 -> 123.34
```

I have tried and everyone is taking examples of  `xx.yy` and showing formating but I will have combination of `xx.00`, `xx.yy` and `xx` only.

My question is different from [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros)

There it is converting 3.140 to 3.14. In my case 3.140 must convert to 3.140 and 3.00 must convert to 3

**SOLUTION:**

I ended up like below

```
for row in df.iterrows():
if row['QTY'].is_integer():
   df['QTY'] = "{:,}".format(int(row['QTY']))
else:
   df['QTY'] = "{:,}".format(float(row['QTY']))
```

Now my df['QTY'] has all values in nicely formatted way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting floats in Python without superfluous zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-in-python-without-superfluous-zeros)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583758/how-to-check-if-a-float-value-is-a-whole-number

Comment: @mkrieger... I am new to python and this is my second day on python.. can you please tell how to use.. ('%f' % x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.') ... I tried this not working... print("('%f' % x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')".format(1234.45))

Comment: Can you please make that into a proper question (considering https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Please concentrate on what i need.. ( 2.0 to 2 ) ,  (2.1 to 2.1 ) , ( 2.10 to 2.10 )... donot remove superflous zeros like .10, .100 if .0 then remove 0 and dot.

Comment: Can you explain the rules by which you want to convert the numbers? Why should `2.0 to 2`, but not `2.10 to 2.1`? What should `3.140` become?

Comment: "please concentrate on..." - please **explain** better what you need.

Comment: Okay so you want to check if a float is a whole number, and if so, convert it to an integer, otherwise leave it as is. Does the second post I linked earlier help?

Comment: Using python code I am generating a report and sending that to my users through email. In that they want to see Quantity column as ( 10 ), (10.123), ( 24 ), (12,365.67 ) and so on.. From database I am getting values as 10.00 , 10.123, 24.00, 12.365.67

Comment: Worked on second link.. will let you know...

Comment: @Ziggler maybe try this, if it is similar to your problem. [how to round/remove traling “.0” zeros in pandas column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403995/1248974)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> b = 123.34
>>> print (("%%12.%df" % (0 if b == round(b) else 2)) % b).strip()
```

Comment: Please, add a few words to explain why you think this is a good answer